# WordPress FusionSlider adds 'http//' after 'http://'

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got this kind of error in console:

GET http://http//example.com/wp-content/uploads/image01.jpg net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I guess it is caused by FusionSlider but I can't even turn it off to see if it is the case. I've updated my webiste's URL and everything works great excepts Sliders.

I am currently working with Avada 3.9.3 and WP 4.4.8
I can also see that my favicon URL is wrong - it is also http://http//example.com/.../

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: I thing it is the other way around. `http://` or `https://` is not found in the original url so it was prefixed to the url. Check the original link.

Comment: Are there any FusionSlider URL settings there? I can't find any.

Comment: Do you ask me? To the issue: 1. I dont thing that a broken protocol `http//` (no `:`) is injected in a url. 2. Also dont thing that a url is manipulated in the middle. 3. So the original url (wherever it comes from) misses the `:` in the protocol. And that is possibly, because it may has typed in by an human. Now a script or whatever trys to fix that, but looks for full protocol `http://` but does not find it so it was added.

Comment: Okay, it was weird but somehow I managed it.

I first searched for patter 'http://http//' to replace it but it was not found.
Weird thing is that when you paste http://http:// to your browser, it turns into http//. I found that by accident and I've used Search & Replace to replace 'http://http://' with 'http://' and now it works. Thank you.